# Can't declare variable from JSON/jQuery object

Tags: php, json, ajax

So, I'm able to return my AJAX request successfully, but my jQuery seems to die once I declare a variable from it.

Here's my JSON response from the console:

```
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"rsp":"1","msg":"show out screen!","time":null,"fn":"Mike","ln":"Maynard","ul":"0"}", status: 200, statusText: "success"}
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "clock.php",   
        type: "POST",   
        async: false,
        data: clockData,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 5500,
        error: function (clockData) {
        //var rsp = (clockData.fn);
        alert('Error');
            //do error
        },


        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (clockData) {            
            console.log(clockData);
            var rsp = clockData[0].rsp;

            console.log(rsp);

            var ul = clockData[0].ul;   
            if(ul=='1') { 
                showUi(); 
            }

            var una = (clockData.fn + ' ' + clockData.ln);
            $('.nameBlock').text(una);
            $('.nameBlockFirst').text(clockData.fn);
            //--> show in ui

            if (rsp=='0') {
                console.log('got here2');
                var dir = 'In'; tcShow(dir);
            }   

            //--> show out ui                           
            if (rsp=='1'){
                alert('trying to show out screen2');        
                var dir = 'Out'; tcShow(dir);
            }

            //--> show in result
            else if (rsp=='2'){
                var time = (clockData.time); var dir = 'in'; showResult(time,dir,ul);
            }
            //--> show out result
            else if (rsp=='3'){
                var time = (clockData.time); var dir = 'out'; showResult(time,dir,ul);
            }
            //--> show message
            else if (rsp=='4'){
                endClock();
            }                   
            else {
                endClock();
            }
        }
    });
```

So, console.log(clockData); Returns fine, but console.log(rsp); Never happens... I'm confused..

Comment: Here's the output of clockData:      
    Object {rsp: "1", msg: "show out screen!", time: null, fn: "Mike", ln: "Maynard"…}

Answer (score 1):

Based off your response text, it looks like it should be `clockData.rsp`. You are doing `clockData[0].rsp` which would imply that clockData is an array. But in fact, your response is a keyed object, not an array.

EDIT: I just noticed you are also using the `complete` method, not `success`. `complete` has a method signature of (jqXHR, textStatus). If you want the response data, you can access it through `JSON.parse(clockData.responseText)`, or better yet, use the `success` callback which has a method signature of (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR). Or for a more modern approach, use promises.

REF: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: var rsp = clockData.rsp; returns undefined :(

Comment: What is the output of console.log(clockData) ?

Comment: Also just realized you are using the `complete` method for your callback, which has a signature of (jqXHR, textStatus). `clockData` in this case will be the request object itself, not your result. You should be using the `success` method, or better yet, AJAX promises.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/